# Pinterest iOS SDK not working properly after Dec 18th

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

The Pinterest SDK was working for me until 18th dec app update. I don't understand why it is not working now. When I try to pin it from my app, it opens the Pinterest app but does not ask for board or do anything to pin it. This is my code, Please help..

```
    sharedObject->_pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:@"1434375"];

- (void)pinIt {
   if ([_pinterest canPinWithSDK]) {
    DLog(@"image url shared on pinterest: %@", self.image_url);
    [_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.image_url]
                            sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self dealUrl:_deal]] 
                          description:_deal.dealShortTitle];
  }
}
```

I have checked the PinIt Demo Code and there also it just takes me to the app, I have checked the urls but didn't understand why it's not working for me..

Comment: pinterest app crashes on share. i'm not sure why this happens

Comment: it was working fine for me , earlier I used to get error if parameters are wrong, Now I don't get any error even when parameters are correct. It suddenly stopped giving any error. It takes me to the pinterest app and nothing happens. Checked the documentation for any change, but no help. It doesn't even crash also.

Comment: i figured out that its crashing because the image size is bigger and network is slow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it , I will also try with a smaller image if it works. But in My case it never crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm awfully late to answer but for sanitys sake. Here's one idea why your app might've had issues with Pinterest.

Pintest App that was released at the end of December introduced a bug that caused pins from their own SDK to fail. This a quote from an email from Pinterest Developer Relations:

> If you are using the Pinterest SDK in your iOS application, then please read on. Starting on 12/12, we released a change to our Pinterest native client on iOS that redirects users to the home feed, instead of showing the pin create dialogue. This means that users will not be able to easily pin from your application via the SDK.
>
> We are aware of this issue, and already have a fix lined up. However, the iTunes App Store is shut down for the holidays, so we do not expect this change to roll out until late December or early January. We do apologize for this inconvenience, and will continue to work on resolving this issue as quickly as we can.

Issue was fixed for the next release in early January.

> I wrote to you a few weeks ago about an error in the iOS SDK. Starting on 12/12, users were redirected to their homefeed, making it more difficult to Pin from your SDK.
>
> This issue was resolved late last week, and users are now correctly directed to the Pin Create dialogue. We wanted to follow up and make sure you were aware of that

Your issue might been fixed with iOS automatically updating latest Pinterest App version.

Edit: Source for email quotes is Jason Costa from Pinterest Developer Relations. I couldn't find anything online. Except their reply to my tweet concerning the issue:

https://twitter.com/ngavini/status/419557669901332481